# Semantic Fixed Menu moves container to top of page

Tags: css, semantic-ui

```
<div className="ui top fixed inverted pointing menu">
<div className="ui container">
```

When I make my menu fixed to the top, it makes the bottom container move up and I'm losing view of the content inside the container.

How can I make it respect the margins ?

I tired mt-4 on the container but it did not work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Line styling did the trick just fine

```
 <div className="ui container" style={{ "padding-top": "50px" }}>
```